# Why my parent element wrap the last word? (floated element inside)

Tags: html, css

I have 3 floated `<li>`, with no width determinated (responsive design). Inside each `<li>`, I have a floated icon +  informations on the right.
[image]

As you can see, the word "route" wrap under, even if the `<li>` element have more than enough space on the right (The red rectangle shows the "container" `<div>`)

Here's the HTML (cleaned) + CSS:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="columns twelve">
                <ul class="quick-infos">
                    <li>
                        <span class="fa fa-phone fa-2x fa-pull-left"></span>
                        VICTORIAVILLE<br />
                        819 357-2494
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="fa fa-phone fa-2x fa-pull-left"></span>
                        DRUMMONDVILLE<br />
                        819 479-8008
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="fa fa-quote-left fa-2x fa-pull-left"></span>
                        Service routier 24 H<br />
                        Camion lourd, agricole et hors route
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="columns four">
                Other things here...
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
ul.quick-infos li {
    float:left; 
    margin-right:3em;
}
```

The floated icons are generated via font-awesome, and they have the class `.pull-left` wich make them float. If I remove the `.pull-left`, the `<li>` works correctly.

So, I want to know why my `<li>` element doesn't render width correctly...

*PS: I know I can work around this with a `white-space:nowrap`, but I really want to know the "reason" :)*

Thx!

Comment: Offhand, I'd say that the text is wrapping because there isn't enough space for it not to wrap...then the floating takes over. A demo here would be useful,

Comment: But as I said, the <li> can take all the place through, since it doesn't have any fixed width.
Also, I've added a `float:right` <div> around my "Service routier 24 H<br />  Camion lourd, agricole et hors route" and it work (Content is not wrapped)

Comment: But you're overriding the styling of the font-awesome content by floating it....at least that's what I assume `fa-pull-left` is doing. Anyway...a demo is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be caused by the nested floats: the `li` is floated left, and the `.fa-pull-left` icon inside is also floated left.

My guess is that the `li`'s width is calculated first, as if there were no floated span inside, and then the `span` is applied, leaving not enough room inside the rest of the `li`, causing the content to wrap.

If someone can come up with a better explanation, I'd be delighted!

Anyway, the solution is to not float the inner span. One example of a working solution would be to give the li some padding and position the span absolutely inside the padding.

```css
ul.quick-infos {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 1em 0;
  list-type: none;
}

ul.quick-infos > li {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 3em;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.quick-infos > li>span.fa-pull-left {
  position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;
  float: none;
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/3tqactye/1/)

(Sorry for not posting all the code in here, but I had to copy FontAwesome's css into the fiddle, so it's a bit much.)

Comment: Hi there! I found your explanation pretty logic! I made some tests and found out that if I remove the 1rst line (Service routier 24 H) and only keep the 2nd line (Camion lourd, agricole et hors route), no wrap is applied.

I also tried to invert the sentences (the longest one above) and no wrap is applied too..!

Don't know if this can lead to something... :)